# Adding Software Repositories

Tags: software-installation

I can't add a repository because when I click Unbuntu Software I do not have a selection for "Software and Updates", just "Updates".  If I click on "Updates" I get a window that says I'm up to date and no other choices.  I assume I am not going to the correct window or?  Please point me in the correct direction, thank you.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? What kind of repository are you trying to add? Please [edit] your question. "Software & Updates" is a program not an option anywhere.

Comment: -1 The title seems misleading. This is a question about how to locate software on the system, not about how to add a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use your [Desktop Search](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/gs-use-system-search.html.en) to find Software & Updates. There are three easy ways to reach Desktop Search in Gnome:

- Click on "activities" in the top bar, or
- Click on the nine-box-grid at the bottom of the Shortcut Bar, or
- Press your [super] key

Don't use Ubuntu Software to look for Software & Updates. They are separate applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am new and have a lot to learn about using Linux.